# Android Activity State Loss

Tags: android, android-activity

Can somebody answer this question for me:

For testing purposes I have created an activity with a for loop in which I'm creating 10 AlertDialogs or 10 DialogFragments.
Immediately after the activity is started I'm pressing the home button to send the app in the background.
If I'm running the showDialog() method to create the DialogFragments the app will crash with:

```
IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

this is expected behavior.

But if I run the showAlert() method to create the AlertDialogs and same as before I'm sending the app to the background the app doesn't crash. When I return to the activity I can see all 10 AlertDialogs.

The question is why does the activity state loss happen with DialogFragment and not with AlertDialog?

I am still changing the UI after the activity's state has been saved. The platform on which I have tested is Android 4.4.2

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity
{
    private FragmentActivity activity = this;
    private MyAsynk myAsynk;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        myAsynk = new MyAsynk();
        myAsynk.execute();
    }

    private class MyAsynk extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        private boolean run = false;

        public MyAsynk()
        {
            run = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10 && run; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//              showAlert("loop " + i);
                showDialog("loop " + i);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void stop()
        {
            run = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();

        if(null != myAsynk)
        {
            myAsynk.stop();
            myAsynk = null;
        }
    }


    private void showAlert(final String txt)
    {
        try
        {
            Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage(txt)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if(null != dialog)
                                {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 


    private void showDialog(final String txt)
    {
        try
        {
            Main.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    MyDialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(txt);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    newFragment.show(ft, "newFragment");
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

MyDialogFragment.java :

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private MyDialogFragment instance;

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String text)
    {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("text", text);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public MyDialogFragment()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Button bu = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bu);

        bu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(null != instance && instance.isVisible())
                    {
                        instance.dismiss(); 
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("text"));

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple, though a bit underwhelming.

The oft-seen `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` exception is actually thrown by the [`FragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) class. The reason why is explained very well in [this post by Alex Lockwood](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html).

`DialogFragments` are Fragments (and thus managed by `FragmentManager`). Therefore, showing dialogs in this way can provoke the exception. However, the implementation of `AlertDialog` is completely different: it doesn't use Fragments at all (indeed, it actually predates Fragments). Hence, no exceptions.